# How to transform a correlation matrix into a single row?

Tags: matrix, correlation

I have a 200x200 correlation matrix text file that I would like to turn into a single row.

e.g.

```
    a       b       c       d       e
a   1.00    0.33    0.34    0.26    0.20
b   0.33    1.00    0.40    0.48    0.41
c   0.34    0.40    1.00    0.59    0.35
d   0.26    0.48    0.59    1.00    0.43
e   0.20    0.41    0.35    0.43    1.00
```

I want to turn it into:

```
a_b     a_c     a_d     a_e     b_c     b_d     b_e     c_d     c_e     d_e
0.33    0.34    0.26    0.20    0.40    0.48    0.41    0.59    0.35    0.43
```

I need a code that can:
1. Join the variable names to make a single row of headers (e.g. turn "a" and "b" into "a_b") and
2. Turn only one half of the correlation matrix (bottom or top triangle) into a single row

A bit of extra information: I have around 500 participants in a study and each of them has a correlation matrix file. I want to consolidate these separate data files into one file where each row is one participant's correlation matrix.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Programing language? Also what have you tried?

Comment: @Mikhail Ideally I would like to use a bash script (maybe awk?), but I'm happy to go through matlab or r, just anything that can get it done. I have tried doing it through matlab but I can't seem to only extract one half of the correlation matrix

Comment: Edit your question + tag it to match whatever language you want, and show some sample code. As it stands this is too broad, and reads like a mandate to  "write my code", rather than a question.